# Negation of filterWhen and hasElement

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm learning Flux and Mono and am hitting a wall when trying to check if a key doesn't exist in redis. I need to filter my flux and want to remove the element if the key exists. I don't find a way to do this in the docs, all I can filter is to keep if the key exists. I need the opposite.

```
client.request(MWS_EU, Orders, ordersRequest, ListOrdersResponse.class)
    .flatMapIterable(listOrdersResponse -> listOrdersResponse.getOrders())
    .filterWhen(order -> isNewOrder(order.getOrderId()))
    .flatMap(...)
```

and the check for redis:

```
private Mono<Boolean> isNewOrder(String orderId) {
    return redisOrders.opsForValue().get(orderId).hasElement();
}
```

What is a clean way to filter my Flux to keep elements only if the key does not exist?

I don't want to use `block()`.

Comment: What about using `.map(b -> !b)` to invert it after `.hasElement()`

Comment: @Lino That works, but it feels wrong to do that. There must be another way to check for empty, isn't there?

Comment: I don't really know redis api and flux. But I assume that actually there is not. Because when providing a boolean, you can always invert it to get the other value. So providing 2 methods doesn't really makes sense. Just look at `Iterator.hasNext()` or `Collections.isEmpty()`, they don't have a counterpart

Comment: Hm, I get your point. @Lino I'll use that then.. Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong. By looking at the Javadoc of the intermediate instances. E.g. from `opsForValue()` or `get(orderId)` you may find some clues for `hasNoElement()` or something

Comment: I've checked that for quite some time, I don't find any method that seems to help there. All I could check for is the `size`, but that doesn't really help either. I think your explanation in the comment before is sensible though, so I'll use map to invert. @Lino

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your method to the following:

```
private Mono<Boolean> isNewOrder(String orderId) {
    return redisOrders.opsForValue().get(orderId).hasElement().map(b -> !b);
}
```

By using the [`map()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method you can just invert the value returned by `hasElement()`.

Comment: This is just absolutely brilliant